# oracle declare a user defined type that can be used across multiple functions and procedure

Tags: oracle, function, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle11g

I have an SQL file that creates other stored procedures/functions. I wanted to make use of a user defined type that can be accessed among the created stored procedures/functions. What is the best way to achieve this? The simplest way that I thought of is to just create that user defined type in every procedure/function.

My user defined type looks something like this:

```
create  type array_t is varray(2) of number;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just execute

```
create  type array_t is varray(2) of number;
```

globally.

Comment: if I try putting this statement inside the sql file that creates other functions/sp then I get error "ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object" does that mean I have already created the type?

Comment: exact, but you can say  `create or replace type` to avoid this error

Comment: or check result of 
select * from all_types where upper(type_name) = 'ARRAY_T';

Answer (score 1):

You can either create the type as a stand-alone item, with a `create [or replace] type` statement, or else include it in a package header. The advantage of a standalone type is that you can use it in SQL queries and as the type for table and view columns. The advantage of a PL/SQL-only declaration is that it simplifies your deployment, and nobody in their right mind would want a `varray` column anyway.

If your deployment process is giving *'name is already used by an existing object'* errors then yes it already exists (perhaps from a previous run). `create or replace` is standard practice and a good idea, although your scripts should define each item in only one place.